# setTimeout not working with angular2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

This is the html code from where i am checking for if the page is idle. And if its idle for a while I need to throw inactivity alert and logout the user.

```
<div *ngIf="environmentData" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" (load)="startTimers()" (mousemove)="resetTimers()" (keypress)="resetTimers()">
```

The functions are defined in typescript component like below: timoutNow variable is set for 10 minutes. But the screen pops the alert everytime the mouse moved or a key is pressed. Why is it not waiting for that time that i have set before showing the alert?

```
// Start timers.
  startTimers() {
    console.log("inside start timers method");
    console.log("time out number is "+this.timoutNow);
    this.timeoutTimer = setTimeout(this.showTimeout(), this.timoutNow);
    // window.location.href = this.environmentData.logoutUrl;
  }

  showTimeout(){
    console.log("inside show timeout");
    bootbox.alert("You are being timed out due to inactivity!");
  }

  // Reset timers.
  resetTimers() {
    console.log("inside reset timers method");
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutTimer);
    this.startTimers();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
this.timeoutTimer = setTimeout(this.showTimeout, <arg2>);  // correct
```

instead of

```
this.timeoutTimer = setTimeout(this.showTimeout(), <arg2>);  // wrong
```

because in the latter, you are immediately invoking the callback function instead of passing the reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. Cant believe that is the mistake.

Comment: Welcome:) I added the explanation for reference.

Comment: Also @PoonkodiSivapragasam you want to gain access to other functions within the class you need to either use the arrow syntax or `.bind(this)`

Comment: @cgatian indeed or, since there is no instance state, why not make it a `function`?

Comment: @cgatian I have added .bind(this) in the showTimeout method to gain access to the local variables used within the class. However, the value is still undefined. Am i missing something? Please see the code below: bootbox.alert("You are being timed out due to inactivity!", function(){ window.location.assign(this.logoutUrl)}.bind(this));